# Binding Data to a UserControl hosted by a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, winrt-xaml

I have a user control which exposes a property which is a long.  I'd like to instantiate this control and bind to the exposed property in a data template.

I'm seeing xaml errors in the resource file.  The ambiguous "must have derivative of panel as the root element".  And when I run this in a debugger, I see that the value of TeamIdx is -1 and is not being set.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TeamScheduleTemplate">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400" Height="600">
        <Team:ScheduleControl TeamIdx="{Binding Idx}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>



public sealed partial class ScheduleControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TeamIdxProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TeamIdx",
        typeof(long),
        typeof(ScheduleControl),
        new PropertyMetadata((long)-1));

    public long TeamIdx
    {
        get { return (long)GetValue(TeamIdxProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TeamIdxProperty, value); }
    }

    public ScheduleControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var team = TeamLookup.GetTeam(TeamIdx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: It turns out that the binding doesn't happen until after the control is constructed.  In retrospect, this makes total sense.  The solution I used is below:

```
public sealed partial class ScheduleControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TeamIdxProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TeamIdx",
        typeof(long),
        typeof(ScheduleControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            (long)-1,
            OnTeamIdxChanged));

    public long TeamIdx
    {
        get { return (long)GetValue(TeamIdxProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TeamIdxProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnTeamIdxChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = (ScheduleControl)sender;
            target.OnTeamIdxChanged((long)e.NewValue);
    }

    private void OnTeamIdxChanged(long id)
    {
        var model = FindModel(id);
        this.DataContext = model;
    }


    public ScheduleControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```